# how to identify whether x and y coordinates are in rectangel using ontouchlistener?

Tags: android

```
public void hatdraw(Canvas canvas,float x,float y) {
     mBitmaps = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.hat);
     srcRect=new Rect(0,0,60,60);
     xrect=(int)x;
     yrect=(int)y;
    Log.d("hatdraw","xrect,yrect"+xrect    +yrect);
    desRect=new Rect(xrect,yrect, xrect+ (srcRect.right - srcRect.left),
            yrect + (srcRect.bottom -srcRect.top));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmaps,srcRect,desRect, null);


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the posted code has to do with the title to this question, but take a look at `Rect.contains(int x, int y)` (or an equivalent method in `RectF`) for that test.

Answer (score 0):

Get touch on bitmap ...

```
if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth()) 
    && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight()))
{
    // if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
}
```